# pandas top n values when group name in multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to find the top n values from a large `DataFrame`.  Keys are combinations of similarly named objects in my first two columns.  However, I'd like to find the max, regardless of which column the key is located.  Better demonstrated by example:

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(10)

pairs = [combo for combo in itertools.combinations(['apple','banana','pear','orange'], 2)]

df = pd.DataFrame(pairs, columns=['a','b'])
df['score'] = np.random.rand(6)
```

The original DataFrame:

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]: a   b   score
     0  apple   banana  0.771321
     1  apple   pear    0.020752
     2  apple   orange  0.633648
     3  banana  pear    0.748804
     4  banana  orange  0.498507
     5  pear    orange  0.224797
```

Here is how I would accomplish my task w/ SQL, assuming I have a database table named fruits that emulates `df` above:

```
uniq = pd.unique(df[['a', 'b']].values.ravel())

df_sql = pd.DataFrame()
for fruit in uniq:
    dfsql_tmp = pd.read_sql_query(
    """SELECT a,b,score FROM fruits
    WHERE a = %s
    OR b = %s
    ORDER BY score DESC
    LIMIT 1;""",
    engine, params=[fruit, fruit])
    
    df_sql = pd.concat([df_sql, dfsql_tmp], ignore_index=True)
```

This gets me exactly what I'm asking, the top n scores from each unique value (from the union of `df['a']` and `df['b']`).  Desired output:

```
In [5]: df_sql
Out[5]: a   b   score
     0  apple   banana  0.771321 #highest apple score
     1  apple   banana  0.771321 #highest banana score
     2  apple   orange  0.633648 #highest orange score
     3  banana  pear    0.748804 #highest pear score
```

---

#### EDIT

This does the trick also, but slow at scale:

```
N=1
df_new = pd.DataFrame()
for fruit in uniq:
    df_tmp = df[(df['a'] == fruit) | (df['b'] == fruit)].sort_values('score', ascending=False).head(N)
    df_new= pd.concat([df_new, df_tmp])
```

---

Is there a better method to get my desired result?  The nested sql query doesn't scale.  I'd rather perform the action on one large `df`.  It's also important to keep the `n`, rather than simply max or min.

Comment: also, please help by editing the title of this question, I had trouble finding the right words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a pretty solution, and I suspect there's better ones out there, but here's a crack at it. This creates a ~550k row x 5 column DataFrame and runs in about 4 seconds on my laptop.

```
import string
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools

np.random.seed(10)
pairs = [combo for combo in itertools.combinations(string.letters + string.digits, 4)]

df = pd.DataFrame(pairs, columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
df['score'] = np.random.rand(len(df))

cols = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
indexes = []

for c in pd.concat([df[col] for col in cols]).unique():
    indexes.append(df[reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, [df[col] == c for col in cols])]['score'].idxmax())
print df.ix[indexes]
```

Add in a `.reset_index()` at the end if you don't want the original indexes preserved in the output.

For top N, instead of doing `.idxmax()`, sort the reduced frame and take the first N indexes with `.iloc[:N]`.